# TFS on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-mac

I have installed visual studio mac on my mac.

I have installed the tfs extension on visual studio mac.

I have connected to the tfs server in our server in office.

It successfully connected and it display the collection. 
BUT it says it has 0 projects. there should be 4 projects in that collection.
User has admin permissions so it shouldnt be the case. Also it does show projects in tfs browser and vs in windows.
what would be the problem? thanks

Comment: What version of VS and TFS are you using?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thanks for your interes tfs is 2017. it was 2013, then I have updated to 2017. I am using visual studio for mac 2017 7.6.3

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT by the way while I try to connect with credentials, even though I entered the right credentials, it doesnt connect(domain textbox is empty). Until I just enter a random text in NTLM Domain textbox. Then it connects the server but it doesnt display any project

Comment: What's the repository type for that 4 projects? Git or TFVC?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT they are TFVC.  By the way the extension gives error. when I enable the extension and then restart visual studio, the visual studio crashes. I have to reinstall visual studio. it is a pain. then when I install it and restart it, the same things happen

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I dont know if you are the reason or not, the problem is solved : ) two days after the issue, I have uninstalled the vs for mac and installed it back, then installed the extension, it worked perfectly. I wasnt expecting, but it worked. thanks if you are in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you match the requirements:

> **Requirements :**
>
> - Visual Studio Community, Professional, or Enterprise for Mac version
>     7.5 or later.
> - Visual Studio Team Services, or Team Foundation Server 2013 and    later.
> - A Project in Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server,    configured to use Team Foundation Version Control.

**[TFS Authentication:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control#tfs-authentication)**

> To connect to TFS, enter the server details and your account
>   credentials. Enter a domain to use NTLM authentication, otherwise
>   leave blank to use basic authentication. Select Add Server:

And for your specific issue -- **I do not see any / all of my projects ：**

> After authenticating you should see the list of projects. By default,
>   only TFS projects to are shown. To see other types of projects, check
>   the "**See all projects**" box.
>
> Keep in mind that projects that are on the server will not appear if
>   you don't have the correct privileges.

Please see [Connecting to Team Foundation version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control) for details.

---

**UPDATE:**

Just try to uninstall the vs for mac, and install it again with the latest version, installed the latest extension. That should be work.

Comment: the user has admin privilages and it can see all projects when I connect them on browser. But not in mac. I suspect that it might be ntlm authentication. While authentication, it doesnt allow me to connect without entering any text to Domain textbox. I just enter "asd" and it connects but no projects.  may it be the case?? what should I enter the domain box. or what is it, how can I configure in TFS? any idea?

Comment: @smoothumut Yean, authentication issue should be the root cause. Please check and confirm which authentication mechanism do you use. Alternatively you can try to enable basic authentication and try if that works...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but it didnt work. I have enabled the basic authentication from iis for tfs but it doesnt connects until I entered a text in domain

Comment: forgive me, it worked, I have successfully connected to the server without ntlm BUT there is still the same issue, the collections are empty

Comment: @smoothumut Are you in an domain environment? or just a work group? Just try to enter the user name like `Domain\user` or `ComputerName\user` ....

Comment: it is not domain environment, but server has name and I entered with that too like SERVERNAMER\myusername . it logins but no projects. should I give extra privilage in somewhere in tfs? or should I install any program to mac in order to see the projects?? I am newbie on this and sorry for dummy questions

Comment: BTW, have you exactly follow the steps mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control#tfs-authentication) to install the extension and connect to TFS? Updating... restart..etc

Comment: Yes I did, then I uninstalled and reinstalled it and now it vs keeps crashing :(
I will let you know about the progress if I make it start again

Comment: @smoothumut Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: Hi, yes it is resolved : )  Two days later I did give a chance. I have uninstalled the vs for mac again, installed it again, installed the extension again, then it worked, it didnt crash !!!, also it starts to display the projects!!!!
I guess, visual studio mac team made the updates on the extension. I had sent the error log as a bug. this might be the reason or you the guys are the reason. I dont know how but thanks to whoever solved the issue. this was urgent to us.

Comment: sorry for bothering, but I have another problem with tfs visual studio for mac. here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52291028/3040893
just let you know if you have any idea about the issue